# why IOptions is getting resolved even if not registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-configuration

In my .NET Core project, I have below settings in Configure method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    //services.AddOptions<UploadConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("UploadConfig"));
}
```

I have not registerd any `IOptions` and I am injecting it in a controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HelloWorldController : ControllerBase
{
    public HelloWorldController(IOptions<UploadConfig> config)
    {
        var config1 = config.Value.Config1;
    }
 }
```

The `IOptions` is getting resolved with the default instance, and I get to know error only when I am trying to use it (and when I expect the value to be not null).

Can I somehow get it to fail, stating the instance type is not registered or something similar? I just want to catch errors as early as possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The options framework is set up by the default host builder as part of its setup, so you do not need to `AddOptions()` yourself. This however also ensures that you can use `IOptions<T>` wherever you want since the framework will provide that exact options object for you.

The way options work is that the framework will always give you a `T` (as long as it can construct one). When you do set up configuration using e.g. [`AddOptions<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsservicecollectionextensions.addoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions_AddOptions__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_) or [`Configure<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.2), what actually happens is that a configuration *action* gets registered for that type `T`. And when an `IOptions<T>` is later resolved, all those registered actions will run in the sequence they are registered.

This means that it’s valid to *not* have configured an options type. In that case, the default values from the object will be used. Of course, this also means that you are not able to detect whether you have actually configured the options type and whether the configuration is actually valid. This usually has to be done when you use the values.

For example, if you require `Config1` to be configured, you should explicitly look for it:

```
public HelloWorldController(IOptions<UploadConfig> config)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config.Value.Config1))
        throw ArgumentException("Config1 is not configured properly");
}
```

An alternative would be to register a *validation action* for a type using [`OptionsBuilder.Validate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.optionsbuilder-1.validate?view=aspnetcore-2.2). This will then be called automatically when you resovle the options object to validate the containing value. That way, you can have the validation set up in a central location:

```
services.AddOptions<UploadConfig>()
    .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("UploadConfig"))
    .Validate(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Config1));
```

Unfortunately, this also means that you can only detect these problems when you actually *use* the values, which can be missed if you are not testing your application thoroughly. A way around this would be to resolve the options once when the application starts and validate them there.

For example, you could just inject your `IOptions<T>` within your startup’s `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IOptions<UploadConfig> uploadOptions)
{
    // since the options are injected here, they will be constructed and automatically
    // validated if you have configured a validate action

    // …
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Alternatively, if you have multiple options you want to validate and if you want to run logic that does not fit into the validation action, you could also create a service that validates them:

```
public class OptionsValidator
{
    private readonly IOptions<UploadConfig> uploadOptions;
    public OptionsValidator(IOptions<UploadConfig> uploadOptions)
    {
        _uploadOptions = uploadOptions;
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_uploadOptions.Value.Config1))
            throw Exception("Upload options are not configured properly");
    }
}
```

And then inject that in your `Configure`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, OptionsValidator optionsValidator)
{
    // validate options explicitly
    optionsValidator.Validate();

    // …
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Whatever you do, keep also in mind that by default the configuration sources are configured to support updating the configuration at run-time. So you will always have a situation in which a configuration can be invalid temporarily at run-time.

Comment: is there any callback or an event triggred which I can subscribe to in case the configuration is updated dynamically? e.g. PostConfigure??

Comment: When you use options that can be reloaded (this only works for `IOptionsSnapshot<T>` not `IOptions<T>` btw), then whenever those options are resolved, the whole “configuration pipeline” will run. So any configure, post-configure, and validation action will run as normal. So you usually don’t need to know _when_ the values actually change. If you do actually need this, you can use an `OptionsMonitor` and register an [`OnChange` action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.optionsmonitor-1.onchange?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: thanks a lot for the updated answer. implemented it with certain customization.

Answer (score 2):

Great answer from *[poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke)*, I just wanna complete it with this that you can fail-fast in your startup file when no configuration is provided:

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var options = Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions").Get<MyOptions>();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options?.MyValue))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("MyValue is not configured!");
    }
}
```

> IOptions configuration values are read lazily. Although the
>   configuration file might be read upon application startup, the
>   required configuration object is only created when IOptions.Value is
>   called for the first time.
>
> When deserialization fails, because of application misconfiguration,
>   such error will only appear after the call to IOptions.Value. This can
>   cause misconfigurations to keep undetected for much longer than
>   required. By reading -and verifying- configuration values at
>   application startup, this problem can be prevented.

This articles also helps you to get the idea:

[Is IOptions Bad?](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/is-ioptions-t-bad/)

[ASP.NET Core 2.2 – Options Validation](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-2-2-options-validation)

Comment: I have implemented `PostConfigure` for that... Thanks for the link, it helped

Comment: While this works fine, I would generally recommend against doing this like that. What this does is verify the *configuration*, not the *options*. Since options can be configured through multiple sources, and configuration is just one of them, I would recommend validating the resulting options instead. This can be done by moving that validation logic into the `Configure` method and injecting the `IOptions<>` there directly to validate (or to trigger validation through a registered validation action).

Comment: @harishr I’ve expanded my answer to show a few code examples on how you could implement this.